# How to make FuzzyFinder pluggin open files in a new graphical tab in MacVim?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, fuzzyfinder

When I use FuzzyFinder plugin to open a new file in MacVim, it opens the new file at the same tab in a new buffer.

How to tell FuzzyFinder to open thoses files in a new MacVim tab?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @Rob I don't think so... MacVim+FuzzyFinder is my programming setup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just founded the answer at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984

> You can open a selected item in
>   various ways:
>
> ```
>     <CR>  (|g:fuf_keyOpen|)        - opens in a previous window. 
>     <C-j> (|g:fuf_keyOpenSplit|)   - opens in a split window. 
>     <C-k> (|g:fuf_keyOpenVsplit|)  - opens in a vertical-split window. 
>     <C-l> (|g:fuf_keyOpenTabpage|) - opens in a new tab page.
> ```

...instead of hitting return, I should press `<CTRL-L>` to open in a new tab

Comment: I am trying to remap these and map <C-n>g:fuf_keyNextMode doesn't seem to work. I'm new to Vim – any hints as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: Ah, got lucky: [let fuf_keyOpenTabpage = '<C-t>'] etc.